# How to show $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon ^2} = \pi \delta (x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, distribution-theory

Show that :

$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow  0} \frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon ^2} = \pi  \delta (x)$

Where $\delta (x)$ is the dirac-delta function.

I can't show that the integral of this over all $x$ is $\pi$

Comment: What does $[]$ signify here? Is it the floor function or just brackets?

Comment: "I can't show that the integral of this over all $x$ is $ \pi$" - even if you do show this, it will not be a proof that the left hand side divided by $\pi$ equals the delta-function

Comment: Should it be $x^2$ in the denominator?

Comment: What you have written is so obviously wrong that it cannot be what you wanted to ask, so I'm voting to close as unclear until your edit this into your actual question.

Comment: Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function for the correct definition of Dirac delta (which is not a function in the proper sense)

Comment: Alright. I fixed it. And I know what a dirac delta function is. I'm coming from physics. I don't care too much about rigor at this moment.

Comment: integrate it against a proper testfunction

Comment: Something must be missing.  The equation as written just isn't true.  $$ \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{\varepsilon}{x^2 + \varepsilon^2} = \frac{0}{x^2 + 0} = \frac{0}{x^2}.$$  This is $0$ if $x \ne 0$ and it's undefined if $x = 0$ (because the left limit would be $-\infty$ and the right limit would be $+\infty$).

Comment: Math is all about rigor, so if you don't care about rigor, please ask your question elsewhere :)

Comment: @tipler The limit is taken in the sense of generalized functions.  So, it is correct in that sense.

Comment: @Dr.MV Several user stated that in the comments that the question is non-sense as stated. But you wrote that considered in a proper context (which you are familiar with) it makes sense. Would you perhaps be willing to add a few words with some context to the question so that it has chance to get reopened? (This comment is addressed to the OP, too.) Or is it sufficient to add that the limit is taken not in classical sens but in the sense of generalized functions (distributions)? (I'll have to rely on your advice since I am not very familiar with this distributions.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you for this comment.  I posted a solution that discusses the interpretation as a regularization of the Dirac Delta.

Answer (score 7):

Since you tagged `distribution theory`, I think the following should work.

For any test function $\varphi(x)\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$, where $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ consists of $C^{\infty}$-smooth functions with compact support (which indicates that $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\varphi(x)=0$). We have the following
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\varepsilon\varphi(x)}{x^{2}+\varepsilon^{2}}dx&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi(x) d\tan^{-1}
\left(\frac{x}{\varepsilon}\right) \\
&=
\left[
  \varphi(x)\tan^{-1}
\left(\frac{x}{\varepsilon}\right)
\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tan^{-1}
\left(\frac{x}{\varepsilon}\right)d\varphi
\end{aligned}
$$
then we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\varepsilon\varphi(x)}{x^{2}+\varepsilon^{2}}dx&=
-\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tan^{-1}
\left(\frac{x}{\varepsilon}\right)d\varphi \\
&=-\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}d\varphi+\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{0}d\varphi \\
&=-\frac{\pi}{2}
\Big[
  \varphi(x)
\Big]_{0}^{\infty}+
\frac{\pi}{2}
\Big[
  \varphi(x)
\Big]_{-\infty}^{0} \\
&=\pi\varphi(0)
\end{aligned}
$$
then
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac{\varepsilon}{x^{2}+\varepsilon^{2}}=\pi\delta(x)$$
in the distributional sense.

Comment: You might consider stating the rationale for interchanging the limit with the integral.  It is the key part of the development and its legitimacy should be justified.

Answer (score 5):

Note that in the classical sense

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}=\begin{cases}0&,x\ne 0\\\\\text{undefined}&,x=0\end{cases}$$

In the sense of generalized functions, the expression

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}\sim \pi \delta(x)$$

means that for all suitable test functions $\phi$ we have

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}\right)\,\phi( x)\,dx=\pi \phi(0) \tag 1$$

To show that $(1)$ is correct we let $\phi$ be a suitable test function.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}\right)\,\phi(x)\,dx&=\phi(0)\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}\right)\,dx+\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}\right)\,\left(\phi(x)-\phi(0)\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\pi\,\phi(0)+\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)\,\left(\phi(\epsilon x)-\phi(0)\right)\,dx
\end{align}$$

The [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)\,\left(\phi(\epsilon x)-\phi(0)\right)\,dx&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)\,\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left(\phi(\epsilon x)-\phi(0)\right)\,dx\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we find that for all test functions $\phi(x)$

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}\right)\,\phi( x)\,dx=\pi \phi(0)$$

as was to be shown!

Answer (score -3):

For $x\ne 0$,
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}=0$$
For $x=0$,
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}=\infty$$
Besides,
$$\int_a^b \frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}dx=\int \frac{1/\epsilon}{1+(x^2/\epsilon^2)}dx$$
$$=\int_a^b \frac{1}{1+(x^2/\epsilon^2)}d(x/\epsilon)$$
$$=\arctan(x)\bigg|_{a/\epsilon}^{b/\epsilon}$$
Now if $a>0, b>0$, then
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to infty}\arctan(x)\bigg|_{a/\epsilon}^{b/\epsilon}=\pi/2 - \pi/2 =0$$
Similary, for $a<0, b<0$, we have
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to infty}\arctan(x)\bigg|_{a/\epsilon}^{b/\epsilon}=(-\pi/2) - (-\pi/2) =0$$
For $a<0, b>0$, we have
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to infty}\arctan(x)\bigg|_{a/\epsilon}^{b/\epsilon}=\pi/2 - (-\pi/2) =\pi$$
Hence
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}=\pi\delta(x)$$

Comment: Thanks. You're right. It shoud be $x^2$ not $x$.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself... Where is the last equation coming from?

Comment: I got it : the problem is that you are proving it acts as $\pi \delta(x)$ on the step functions, but you don't explain in what (Banach) space you are, so it let us think you don't know the theory of distributions/test functions